# Complex query when try to join a table to an array in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using EF to join **Letter** table to an long **Array** just after this line I got complex query error! there is no any query before this

```
if (filter.DocumentSubjectID != null && filter.DocumentSubjectID.Length > 0)
            {
                letter = letter.Join(filter.DocumentSubjectID, left => left.DocumentSubjectID, right => right, (l, r) => l);
            }
```

When I omit this line every thing is fine and the query execute with more complexity than this in the next lines! I know my problem is in the join structure but I don't know how should I do this in correct form!

Comment: filter.DocumentSubjectID is an array of lone!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with omit join line, I replace join line with a two line above

```
List<long> lst_DS = filter.DocumentSubjectID.ToList<long>();
letter = letter.Where(p => lst_DS.Contains(p.DocumentSubjectID.Value));
```

there in no contain method and int[] so I convert it to List and then use **contain** method instead of using **join** method!